# How to edit file outside Python directory?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to edit a file outside my Python directory(edit files inside Python directory works). my Python directory is in `c:\Users\test\pycharmproject\pythonproject`. while debugging, the code can see all the files that end with `.txt`. in my case, I want to edit `test.txt`.but the code does not add the string to it. the code ends without any errors.
The code:

```
def foo(folderPath, fileEx, text):
    for file in os.listdir(folderPath):
       if file.endswith(fileEx):
          f=open(file, "a")
          f.write(text)
          f.close()
          print(folderPath, fileEx)#c:\Users\test, text.txt

foo("c:\\Users\\test", ".txt", "-----")
```

The code needs to search all the files that end with `".txt"` and add to it some string.

While I'm trying to do that without the Function I can edit that file that is outside my python directory. for example:

```
f=open("c:\\Users\\test\\file.txt", "a")
f.write("----")
f.close()
```

Comment: You need to include the folderPath when opening the file `open(f"{folderPath}/{file}", a)`